# MYSQL - Get records who doesn't have referral

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
table users - id, username, ref_id
table ref - id, name
```

How to get ids who doesn't have a ref? (ref_id == NULL)

example data:

```
table users:
1, admin, 1
2, mike, NULL

table ref:
1, test
2, tester
3, nick
```

RESULT: 2,3 (free IDs)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT r.id AS id
 FROM users AS u
RIGHT JOIN ref as r
 ON ( u.ref_id = r.id )
WHERE u.ref_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Note that RIGHT JOINs are vanshingly rare